# Как через WebSocket отправить файл на Golang

Tags: файлы, golang, websocket

я хотел бы знать можно ли отправлять файлы на go чeрез ws? Пачками байтов или как?

Comment: На любом языке можно передавать файлы через вебсокеты, именно в виде байт.

Answer (score 0):

отправляем файл в виде байт. берем байты и сохраняем куда хотим

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

const HandshakeTimeoutSecs = 10

type UploadHeader struct {
    Filename string
    Size     int
}

type UploadStatus struct {
    Code   int    `json:"code,omitempty"`
    Status string `json:"status,omitempty"`
    Pct    *int   `json:"pct,omitempty"` // File processing AFTER upload is done.
    pct    int
}

type wsConn struct {
    conn *websocket.Conn
}

func upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    wsc := wsConn{}
    var err error

    // Open websocket connection.
    upgrader := websocket.Upgrader{HandshakeTimeout: time.Second * HandshakeTimeoutSecs}
    wsc.conn, err = upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error on open of websocket connection:", err)
        return
    }
    defer wsc.conn.Close()

    // Get upload file name and length.
    header := new(UploadHeader)
    mt, message, err := wsc.conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error receiving websocket message:", err)
        return
    }
    if mt != websocket.TextMessage {
        wsc.sendStatus(400, "Invalid message received, expecting file name and length")
        return
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(message, header); err != nil {
        wsc.sendStatus(400, "Error receiving file name and length: "+err.Error())
        return
    }
    if len(header.Filename) == 0 {
        wsc.sendStatus(400, "Filename cannot be empty")
        return
    }
    if header.Size == 0 {
        wsc.sendStatus(400, "Upload file is empty")
        return
    }

    // Create temp file to save file.
    var tempFile *os.File
    if tempFile, err = ioutil.TempFile("", "websocket_upload_"); err != nil {
        wsc.sendStatus(400, "Could not create temp file: "+err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer func() {
        tempFile.Close()
        // *** IN PRODUCTION FILE SHOULD BE REMOVED AFTER PROCESSING ***
        // _ = os.Remove(tempFile.Name())
    }()

    // Read file blocks until all bytes are received.
    bytesRead := 0
    for {
        mt, message, err := wsc.conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            wsc.sendStatus(400, "Error receiving file block: "+err.Error())
            return
        }
        if mt != websocket.BinaryMessage {
            if mt == websocket.TextMessage {
                if string(message) == "CANCEL" {
                    wsc.sendStatus(400, "Upload canceled")
                    return
                }
            }
            wsc.sendStatus(400, "Invalid file block received")
            return
        }

        tempFile.Write(message)

        bytesRead += len(message)
        if bytesRead == header.Size {
            tempFile.Close()
            break
        }

        wsc.requestNextBlock()
    }

    // *****************************
    // *** Process uploaded file ***
    // *****************************
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        wsc.sendPct(i * 10)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }

    wsc.sendStatus(200, "File upload successful: "+fmt.Sprintf("%s (%d bytes)", tempFile.Name(), bytesRead))
}

func (wsc wsConn) requestNextBlock() {
    wsc.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("NEXT"))
}

func (wsc wsConn) sendStatus(code int, status string) {
    if msg, err := json.Marshal(UploadStatus{Code: code, Status: status}); err == nil {
        wsc.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, msg)
    }
}

func (wsc wsConn) sendPct(pct int) {
    stat := UploadStatus{pct: pct}
    stat.Pct = &stat.pct
    if msg, err := json.Marshal(stat); err == nil {
        wsc.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, msg)
    }
}

func showJS(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", webPage)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", showJS)
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", upload)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
}

var webPage = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<br>
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="file" />
<br><br>
<span id="uploadButton">
  <button id="upload">Upload</button>
</span>
<span id="cancelButton" style="display: none;">
  <button id="cancel" style="color: red">CANCEL</button>
</span>
<br>
<br>
Upload %: <output id="pct"></output>
<br>
<br>
Status Messages: <output id="list"></output>
</body>
<script>
    var blockSize = 1024 * 1024;
    var ws;
    var filePos;
    var file;
    var reader;
    var blob;
    var cancel = false;
    function readBlob() {
        var first = filePos;
        var last = first + blockSize
        if (last > file.size) {
            last == file.size;
        }
        blob = file.slice(first, last);
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    }
    document.querySelector('#upload').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('pct').innerHTML = '';
        filePos = 0;
        reader = new FileReader();
        cancel = false;
        if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
            var files = document.getElementById('uploadFile').files;
            if (!files.length) {
                alert('Please select a file!');
                return;
            }
            file = files[0];
            document.getElementById('uploadButton').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('cancelButton').style.display = 'block';
            // Open and configure websocket connection.
            ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/upload");
            ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
            // Send filename and size to the server when the connection is opened.
            ws.onopen = function(evt) {
                header = '{"filename":"' + file.name + '","size":' + file.size + '}';
                ws.send(header);
            };
            // Initiate the file transfer by reading the first block from disk.
            readBlob();
            // Send the next file block to the server once it's read from disk.
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                    ws.send(blob);
                    filePos += blob.size;
                    document.getElementById('pct').innerHTML = filePos / file.size * 100.0;
                    if (filePos >= file.size || cancel) {
                        document.getElementById('cancelButton').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('uploadButton').style.display = 'block';
                    }
                }
            };
            // Process message sent from server.
            ws.onmessage = function(e) {
                // Server only sends text messages.
                if (typeof e.data === "string") {
                    // "NEXT" message confirms the server received the last block.
                    if (e.data === "NEXT") {
                        // If we're not cancelling the upload, read the next file block from disk.
                        if (cancel) {
                            document.getElementById('cancelButton').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('uploadButton').style.display = 'block';
                        } else {
                            readBlob();
                        }
                    // Otherwise, message is a status update (json).
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + e.data + '</ul>';
                    }
                }
            };
            ws.onclose = function(evt) {
                ws = null;
            };
            ws.onerror = function(evt) {
                ws.close();
                ws = null;
                return false;
            };
        }
    }, false);
    document.querySelector('#cancel').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        cancel = true;
        ws.send("CANCEL");
    }, false);
</script>
</html>
`
```

Comment: а почему когда я добавляю свой dir в TempFile код просто перестает работать? Он создает пустой файл, и все

Comment: не знаю как вы добавили свой dir. может вы пишете в директорию, а не в файл? сначала нужно создать файл, потом написать в него